# Django - From inline to list display

Tags: django, django-admin

For code below I'd like to display last 10 tasks (`TaskInline`) in `UserAdmin` and to have a button under those 10 tasks (in inline) that would lead to `TaskAdmin` with tasks filtered by the user.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    performer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TaskInline(admin.TabularInline):
    max_num = 10  # display last 10 tasks


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = TaskInline,


@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = 'performer',
```

How can I do this? Should I change template for `TaskInline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** you're missing `user` field in `Task`.

Overwrite `change_form.html` template and add

```
{% block inline_field_sets %}
    {{ block.super }}
     <a href="{% url 'admin:YOURAPP_task_changelist' %}?user__id__exact={{ object_id }}">View all tasks</a>
{% endblock %}
```

In case needed, here is how to overwrite your template for `User` only
Create html file `YOURAPP/templates/admin/YOURAPP/User/change_form.html` and add

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}

{% block inline_field_sets %}
    {{ block.super }}
     <a href="{% url 'admin:YOURAPP_task_changelist' %}?user__id__exact={{ object_id }}">View all tasks</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Then your `UserAdmin` will look like this

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = TaskInline,
    change_form_template = 'admin/YOURAPP/User/change_form.html'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user following code for creating tabular inlines:

```
class TaskInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Task
    extra = 1
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Task.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', ...]
    inlines = (TaskInline,)
```

Comment: This will return `Task`s for the person viewing not the actual `User` object.